# .htaccess modrewrite to a file not directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I use ModRewrite in the .htaccess to redirect /admin to admin.php and not to show the /admin directory.

This: RewriteRule ^admin$ admin.php currently shows the /admin directory rather than going to the script.

I've done some googling but can't seem to get the right keywords.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting `Options -Indexes` together with that rule?

Comment: I'm a total noob with .htaccess. I will google that. Thanks

Comment: No worries :) [Here is the relevant doc page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options).

Comment: Does any other RewriteRule work? Your RewriteRule seems to be ok and should work. Did you set BasePath?

Comment: All my RewriteRules are working. Eg I have ^upload$ going to upload.php. But if a directory exists with the same name then the directory listing is shown instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code in your htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex admin.php
```

Comment: `Options Indexes` is not a good idea when you care about security.

Comment: I have Options -Indexes. Setting DirectoryIndex works if the admin.php file was in the admin directory, but it is in the root folder.

Comment: Thank you Pouya. Your answer was useful but it won't let me up vote yet.